# db update trouble with SQLite in java

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I am having trouble with updating my sqlite database with the following code. Any ideas, what could be wrong here?

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB2", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (Id VARCHAR, BetSum VARCHAR, Bet VARCHAR, Bank VARCHAR, Previous VARCHAR);");

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable;", null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int count = cursor.getInt(0);
            if (cursor.getInt(0)==0)
            {
                ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
                newValues.put("Previous","717");
                db.update("MyTable", newValues, "id=1", null)  
            }
       }
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? Is it crashing? If so, post your logcat.

Comment: If the select count() returns 0, there are no rows in the table, so there's nothing you can update. Try inserting something first.

Comment: The problem lies with in the update function. Even if delete the if-clause it's not updating the row.

Comment: Use `insert`, not `update`.